# Save multimple image in storage with some empty image

Tags: android, bitmap, storage

I have few questions about Images, bitmap particularly. 
In my app that I currently develop, I have like 15 icons that each has on click function to open the camera and shows the result on those icons (like thumbnails).
On resultCode `RESULT_OK`, I get the bitmap data that from `getExtras.get("data")` 
Then store it inside bitmap variable. Like below

```
bitmap1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

I have another 14 bitmaps variable.
Now what I'm trying to do is saving those bitmaps to internal storage by a save button click. But first I place them into an array to make it easier.

```
Bitmap[] bitmapArr = {bitmap1,bitmap2,bitmap3,bitmap4,bitmap5,bitmap6,bitmap7,bitmap8,bitmap9,bitmap10,
                bitmap11,bitmap12,bitmap13,bitmap14,bitmap15};
```

Then read each data to format it to PNG and save it to the internal storage.

```
for(int i=0; i<filename.length; i++){
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(filename[i]));
            bitmapArr[i].compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
            outputStream.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filename[i].getAbsolutePath(), filename[i].getName(), filename[i].getName());

            DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
            db.addData(new Foto(fDate,siteid,filename[i].getName(),filename[i].getAbsolutePath()));
        }
```

I successfully save it into the internal storage only if I capture all the 15 images. If I capture less than that...The app will immediately stop and not save the images. 
I tried to handle it with declare the 15 bitmaps as null in oncreate method. But that doesn't seem to solve the issues.

There is probably something that I've been missing here.

Comment: in for() loop, check your `file != null` before save it

Comment: what if I want to save that image even if its null? Cus I need to save the image to be uploaded later to the database with fixed column

Comment: In case saving data in database, you can save null data but it will not work if saving on Media. It is due to media specify the kind of specify data saving on it. As you see, MediaStore.Images.Media only for image, not for another type(video, db, etc and even null type). And if you debug `inserImage`, you will see it try to open `FileInputStream' via the file path and throw exception if the file is not exist.

Comment: `and save it to the database` ??? Quite confusing description. You are not storing them in YOUR database. Instead you insert them in the mediastore. A very different thing.

Comment: If your app crashes yoh can find the reason in the logcat. Please tell which exception you get.

Comment: `bitmapArr[i].compress(` You cannot call compress() if `bitmapArr[i]==null` which you do now i think. So check before use.

Comment: I just found a way to get thru it....I get resource from drawable...the 'no image' image that fills the image thats not get captured

Comment: Thank u tho for the answer...now should I close this question?

Comment: @greenapps sorry I forgot to include the script of storing the data to database...I use Volley POST